# Many records match query, but mysql shows only first

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have many records that match this query but mysql only shows the first one. What can I do to fix it?
I am trying to join three tables with this    SQL query:

```
SELECT IDcampJour, NomCamp, PrixCamp, Activite.NomActivite, Arrondissement.NomArrondis
FROM CampJour 
JOIN Arrondissement
ON CampJour.IDcampJour = Arrondissement.IDarrondiss
JOIN Activite 
ON CampJour.IDcampJour = Activite.IDactivite 
WHERE  CampJour.Activiteid = 3;
```

**Sample data**

Table Arrondissement

```
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   |IDarrondiss |                 NomArrondis                  |
   |----------- | ---------------------------------------------|
   |     1      |               Ahuntsic-Cartierville          |
   |     2      |                       Anjou                  |
   |     3      |       Côte-des-Neiges–Notre-Dame-de-Grâce    |
   |     4      |                      Lachine                 |
   |     5      |                      LaSalle                 |
   |     6      |           L’Île-Bizard–Sainte-Geneviève      |
   |     7      |           Mercier–Hochelaga-Maisonneuve      |
   |     8      |                   Montréal-Nord              |
   |     9      |                     Outremont                |
   |    10      |                 Pierrefonds-Roxboro          |
   |    11      |                Le Plateau-Mont-Royal         |
   |    12      |      Rivière-des-Prairies–Pointe-aux-Trembles|
   |    13      |            Rosemont–La Petite-Patrie         |
   |    14      |                   Saint-Laurent              |
   |    15      |                   Saint-Léonard              |
   |    16      |                   Le Sud-Ouest               |
   |    17      |                      Verdun                  |
   |    18      |                    Ville-Marie               |
   |    19      |     Villeray–Saint-Michel–Parc-Extension     |
   -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table Activite

```
----------------------------
|IDactivite|  NomActivite  |
----------------------------
|     1    |     Hokey     |
|     2    |    Football   | 
|     3    |   Basketball  |
|     4    |     Soccer    |
----------------------------
```

Table CampJour

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|IDcampJour|   NomCamp       |      AdresseCamp       |    SiteWebCamp    |        DecriptionCamp      | PrixCamp |  Arrondissid | GroupAgeid | Activiteid|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1    | Camp de Verdum  |   0000 Rue de Verdum   |   www.google.com  |      Lorem ipsum dolor...  |    10    |      17      |      1     |     1     |     
|     2    |  Camp Outremont |   0000 Rue Outremont   |   www.google.com  |      Lorem ipsum dolor...  |    25    |      9       |      3     |     3     |
|     3    | Camp Outremont3 |   0300 Rue Outremont   |   www.google.com  |      Lorem ipsum dolor...  |    25    |      9       |      3     |     3     |
|     4    |   Camp Lachine  |    0000 Rue Lachine    |   www.google.com  |      Lorem ipsum dolor...  |    10    |      4       |      4     |     4     |
|     5    | Camp La Salle 2 |   1000 Rue La Salle    |   www.google.com  |      Lorem ipsum dolor...  |    5     |      5       |      2     |     2     |
|     6    | Camp La Salle 3 |   1100 Rue La Salle    |   www.google.com  |      Lorem ipsum dolor...  |   10     |      5       |      1     |     3     |
|     7    | Camp Outremont2 |   1000 Rue Outremont   |   www.google.com  |      Lorem ipsum dolor...  |    5     |      9       |      4     |     4     |
|     8    |Camp de La Salle |  0000 Rue de La Salle  |   www.google.com  |      Lorem ipsum dolor...  |    5     |      5       |      2     |     2     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***Desired Results***

All the camps that have the IDactivite =3; as follows:

```
NomCamp            PrixCamp     Activite      Arrondissement     
Camp Outremont       25        Basketball       Outremont
Camp Outremont3      25        Basketball       Outremont
Camp La Salle 3      10        Basketball        LaSalle
```

Comment: I would believe MySQL.  And check the `JOIN` conditions.  They don't look right to me.  That is why sample data and desired results are so helpful.

Comment: Why are you comparing CampJour.IDcampJour = Activite.IDactivite? These should be matching id's

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I just edited my question. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is actually returning two records: `Camp Outremont` and `Camp Outremont3` as shown here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26fead/1/0

There are two mistakes in your current query. The first one is below:

```
JOIN Arrondissement
ON CampJour.IDcampJour = Arrondissement.IDarrondiss
```

it should be

```
JOIN Arrondissement
ON CampJour.Arrondissid = Arrondissement.IDarrondiss
```

because the value of `CampJour.Arrondissid` is what matches `Arrondissement.IDarrondiss` according to your sample data.

The second mistake is below:

```
JOIN Activite 
ON CampJour.IDcampJour = Activite.IDactivite
```

it should be

```
JOIN Activite 
ON CampJour.Activiteid = Activite.IDactivite
```

because the value of `CampJour.Activiteid` is what matches `Activite.IDactivite` according to your sample data.

Your SQL query should be as below

```
SELECT IDcampJour, NomCamp, PrixCamp, Activite.NomActivite, Arrondissement.NomArrondis
FROM CampJour 
JOIN Arrondissement
ON CampJour.Arrondissid = Arrondissement.IDarrondiss
JOIN Activite 
ON CampJour.Activiteid = Activite.IDactivite 
WHERE  CampJour.Activiteid = 3;
```

and it will show your desired results, see the demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26fead/3